# Locked up "Signing out" after an upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Yesterday I upgraded a Toshiba laptop from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

All seemed to go well until trying to sign out. It displays a blue screen with rotating dots and displays "Signing Out".

How to get out of this? It resumes after powering down and starting up.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a long shot, but it will get your computer useable, and will likely make a solution possible or make the problem findable. I see no other answers to date so here goes:

Using another computer, download the Puppy Linux OS onto a disc (and then a thumb drive if your computer doesn't have a CD driver). Plug it into the problem computer. Then as soon as you start it, press the `F2` key repeatedly. (That puts you into the Start Up phase, which happens automatically when you normally start the computer).

At each blue screen use the instructions at the bottom of the screen. At the first screen scroll down to Boot Sequence. Then move `USB` drive or `CD` to the top of the list (whichever you plugged the Puppy drive into). Then exit the startup, and the start procedure will continue, and find the Puppy OS there. Then you should have a regular desktop view somewhat similar to Windows 7 or so.

Linux OS's are often very good for trouble shooting systems.

I'm sorry I can't help you any further, but this will get you a big step 'into' your computer.

Puppy Linux is so small it doesn't even need the hard drive, but can operate from the RAM. The HD could even be removed. I used Puppy this way for another problem. I keep a copy on hand.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)